# A problem involving classification of data

Tags: list-manipulation

Toady, I encountered a problem while trying to classify certain data.

I have the coordinates of six points.

```
data = {{0.349661, 0.380297}, {0.858156, 0.8442}, {0.906745, 0.171579},
 {0.0847783, 0.277227}, {0.198453, 0.40206}, {0.941614, 0.347187}};
```

I want to perform some operation on the x coordinate. The operation is as follows. If the x coordinate in one of the following ranges

```
{{0.0423892, 0.141616}, {0.141616, 0.274057}, {0.274057, 0.603909}, 
 {0.603909, 0.882451}, {0.882451, 0.924179}, {0.924179, 0.959049}}
```

The new x coordinate will have the value 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 respectively.

I tried the following:

```
judge = {{0.0423892, 0.141616}, {0.141616, 0.274057}, {0.274057, 0.603909}, 
   {0.603909, 0.882451}, {0.882451, 0.924179}, {0.924179, 0.959049}};
Which[Sequence @@ 
       Flatten@Table[{judge[[i, 1]] < # < judge[[i, 2]] &, i}, {i, 1, 6}]] /@
 data[[All, 1]]
```

However, it failed. I discovered the mistake was

```
Table[{judge[[i, 1]] < # < judge[[i, 2]] &, i}, {i, 1, 6}]
```

I got

> ```
> {{judge[[i, 1]] < #1 < judge[[i, 2]] &, 1}, 
>  {judge[[i, 1]] < #1 < judge[[i, 2]] &, 2},
>  {judge[[i, 1]] < #1 < judge[[i, 2]] &, 3},
>  {judge[[i, 1]] < #1 < judge[[i, 2]] &, 4},
>  {judge[[i, 1]] < #1 < judge[[i, 2]] &, 5},
>  {judge[[i, 1]] < #1 < judge[[i, 2]] &, 6}}
> ```

rather than

> ```
>  {{judge[[1, 1]] < #1 < judge[[1, 2]] &, 1}, 
>   {judge[[2, 1]] < #1 < judge[[2, 2]] &, 2},
>   {judge[[3, 1]] < #1 < judge[[3, 2]] &, 3},
>   {judge[[4, 1]] < #1 < judge[[4, 2]] &, 4},
>   {judge[[5, 1]] < #1 < judge[[5, 2]] &, 5},
>   {judge[[6, 1]] < #1 < judge[[6, 2]] &, 6}}
> ```

Comment: Do I understand this correctly: You want to get a list of which range number each of the first entries in the data list belong to?

Comment: You could try `Evaluate`. Or inject a value for `i` using `With`.

Answer (score 5):

```
data = {{0.349661, 0.380297}, {0.858156, 0.8442}, {0.906745, 0.171579}, 
        {0.0847783, .277227},  {0.198453, 0.40206}, {0.941614, 0.347187}};
ints = {{0.0423892, 0.141616}, {0.141616, 0.274057}, {0.274057, 0.603909}, 
        {0.603909, 0.882451}, {0.882451, 0.924179}, {0.924179, 0.959049}};

{IntegerPart@ InverseFunction[Interpolation[ints[[All, 1]], InterpolationOrder -> 1]]
                                                           @#[[1]], #[[2]]} & /@ data

(*
{{3, 0.380297}, {4, 0.8442}, {5, 0.171579}, {1, 0.277227}, {2,  0.40206}, {6, 0.347187}}
*)
```

Comment: I spy... two fives...

Comment: @rasher Oh, I forgot the `InterpolationOrder` part. Thanks for checking.

Answer (score 4):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly...

```
data = {{0.349661, 0.380297}, {0.858156, 0.8442}, {0.906745, 0.171579}, 
        {0.0847783, 0.277227}, {0.198453, 0.40206}, {0.941614, 0.347187}};

intervals = 
  Interval /@ {{0.0423892, 0.141616}, {0.141616, 0.274057}, {0.274057, 0.603909},  
               {0.603909, 0.882451}, {0.882451, 0.924179}, {0.924179, 0.959049}};

result=First@Pick[Range@Length@intervals, IntervalMemberQ[intervals, #]] & /@ data[[All, 1]]

(* {3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 6} *)
```

If you actually want to change the data itself, follow by

```
data[[All, 1]] += result
```

If you want to *replace* the `x` data, follow instead with

```
data[[All, 1]] = result
```

Comment: I think `data[[All, 1]] = result` is what the OP wants.

Comment: Lots of options, but I think your use of `Interval` is the "right" approach given the OPs intent.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {{0.349661, 0.380297}, {0.858156, 0.8442}, {0.906745, 
    0.171579}, {0.0847783, 0.277227}, {0.198453, 0.40206}, {0.941614, 0.347187}};
data2 = {{0.0423892, 0.141616}, {0.141616, 0.274057}, {0.274057, 
    0.603909}, {0.603909, 0.882451}, {0.882451, 0.924179}, {0.924179, 0.959049}};
data3 = Range[6]
f[{x_, y_}] := 
  Evaluate@Piecewise@Transpose@{{#, y} & /@ data3, #1 < x <= #2 & @@@ data2};
f /@ data
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for variety:

```
data = {{0.349661, 0.380297}, {0.858156, 0.8442}, {0.906745, 
    0.171579}, {0.0847783, 0.277227}, {0.198453, 0.40206}, {0.941614, 
    0.347187}};
int = {{0.0423892, 0.141616}, {0.141616, 0.274057}, {0.274057, 
    0.603909}, {0.603909, 0.882451}, {0.882451, 0.924179}, {0.924179, 
    0.959049}};
```

Changing the intervals and sorting data:

```
ord = Union[Flatten@int];
s = SortBy[data, First];
```

Deriving (sorted) result:

```
ans = MapThread[{Total[Map[Function[x, Boole[#1 > x]], ord]], #2} &, 
  Transpose@s]
```

yields:

```
{{1, 0.277227}, {2, 0.40206}, {3, 0.380297}, {4, 0.8442}, {5, 
  0.171579}, {6, 0.347187}}
```

If original order desired:

```
ans[[Ordering@Ordering[data[[All, 1]]]]]
```

->

```
{{3, 0.380297}, {4, 0.8442}, {5, 0.171579}, {1, 0.277227}, {2, 
  0.40206}, {6, 0.347187}}
```

Generalizing:

```
fun[list_, i_, p_: 0] := Module[{st, res, a},
  st = SortBy[list, First];
  res = MapThread[{Total[Map[Function[x, Boole[#1 > x]], i]], #2} &, 
    Transpose@st];
  If[p != 0, a = res[[Ordering@Ordering[list[[All, 1]]]]], a = res];
  a
  ]
```

(default is p=0 sorted, otherwise original).

Test: consider sorting random reals between 0 and 10  for intervals:{{0, 2}, {2, 4}, {4, 6}, {6, 8}, {8, 10}}:

```
test = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {10, 2}]
Grid[{#1, #2 /. 
     Thread[Range[5] -> Partition[Range[0, 10, 2], 2, 1]], #2} & @@@ 
  Transpose[{test, fun[test, Range[0, 10, 2], 1]}], Frame -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
indexF = Function[{x}, Piecewise[MapIndexed[{First@#2, #[[1]] <= x <= #[[2]]} &, #]]]&;
h = MapAt[indexF[#2], #1, {All, 1}] &;


data = {{0.349661, 0.380297}, {0.858156, 0.8442}, {0.906745,  0.171579},
        {0.0847783, .277227}, {0.198453, 0.40206}, {0.941614, 0.347187}};
ints = {{0.0423892, 0.141616}, {0.141616, 0.274057}, {0.274057, 0.603909}, 
        {0.603909, 0.882451}, {0.882451, 0.924179}, {0.924179,  0.959049}};

h[data, ints]
(*{{3,0.380297},{4,0.8442},{5,0.171579},{1,0.277227},{2,0.40206},{6,0.347187}} *)
```

Comment: @kguker,Sorry, I can not achieve a result witj your solution, namely, it give some information.

Answer (score 1):

Fixing the OP's original function :-

```
data = {{0.349661, 0.380297}, {0.858156, 0.8442}, {0.906745, 0.171579},
   {0.0847783, 0.277227}, {0.198453, 0.40206}, {0.941614, 0.347187}};

judge = {{0.0423892, 0.141616}, {0.141616, 0.274057}, {0.274057, 0.603909},
   {0.603909, 0.882451}, {0.882451, 0.924179}, {0.924179, 0.959049}};

Which @@ Flatten@
    Table[{judge[[i, 1]] < # < judge[[i, 2]], i}, {i, 1, 6}] & /@ data[[All, 1]]
```

> {3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 6}

Answer (score 0):

For more variety, using a rule replacement

```
data = {{0.349661, 0.380297}, {0.858156, 0.8442}, {0.906745, 
    0.171579}, {0.0847783, 0.277227}, {0.198453, 0.40206}, {0.941614, 
    0.347187}};
range = {{0.0423892, 0.141616}, {0.141616, 0.274057}, {0.274057, 
    0.603909}, {0.603909, 0.882451}, {0.882451, 0.924179}, {0.924179, 
    0.959049}};
data[[All, 1]] /. (x_ /; x < #[[2]] -> #[[1]] & /@ 
   Transpose[{Range[1, 6], Last /@ range}])
```

I sacrifice rigor for compactness here, since the rules will assign `x < 0.0423892 -> 1` instead of undefined.

### update

Borrowing from @rasher and using `Association` in v10

```
#[[1]] -> #[[2]] & /@ Transpose[{Range[1, 6], Interval /@ range}]
assoc = Association[%]
With[{dlist = #}, Keys@Select[assoc, IntervalMemberQ[#, dlist] &]] & /@
   data[[All, 1]] // Flatten
```